# When do you control for initial judgment vs. take the difference between first and second judgment?

Tags: spss

I am analyzing data for my dissertation, and I have participants see initial information, make judgments, see additional information, and make the same judgments again. I don't know how or if I need to control for these initial judgments when doing analyses about the second judgments.

I understand that the first judgments cannot be covariates because they are affected by my IV/manipulations. Also, I only expect the second judgments to change for some conditions, so if I use the difference between first and second judgments, I only expect that to change for two of my four conditions.

Comment: Wecome to Stack-Overflow! Your question is not about programming, which is the topic for this site - please post it here: stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle comparisons between the first and second judgments would be as paired data. If condition is a between-subjects factor, then a between x within design using repeated measures ANOVA or for judgments where the scaling isn't such that you're willing to make assumptions necessary for linear models, using a generalized linear model setup that handles repeated measurements might be applicable. In SPSS for linear models, you can set up the judgments as two different variables and condition as a third, then use Analyze>General Linear Models>Repeated Measures. For generalized linear models you can use with generalized estimating equations (GEE) or mixed models, though these require a fair amount of data to be reliable. In the menus, there are Analyze>Generalized Linear Models>Generalized Estimating Equations and Analyze>Mixed Models>Generalized Linear, respectively. Each of these requires data setup for repeated measures to be in the "long" or "narrow" format, where you have a subject ID variable, a time index, the judgment variable, and the condition variable. You'd have two cases per subject, one for each time point.